# Anyone know where 'ZBAR_LIB' is in Windows?(Ruby on Rails-zbar-gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Anyone know where 'ZBAR_LIB' is in Windows?
I try to use zbar gem ,and get this error message ask me to install zbar c library ,then I download and install zbar installer for windows from its site,but still got this error

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar/lib.rb:12:in `rescue in <module:ZBar>': Didn't find libzbar on your system (LoadError)
Please install zbar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) or set ZBAR_LIB if it's in a weird place
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't look for ZBAR_LIB, look for "libzbar" by searching.
Then set in your path ZBAR_LIB = path/to/install/bin/libzbar-0.dll

It might be called libzbar-0.dll and it's in the bin, but you should probably just look for it, rather than libzbar.dll in the lib.

I think you just confused the ZBAR_LIB with the actual error:

```
Didn't find libzbar on your system (LoadError)
```

Comment: I think you need to specify libzbar.dll as the file at then end of the path